Solar garden light inductor wattage?
I have a few solar garden lights that works and I wanted to increase its light output. I saw its circuit and it's using a IC YX8018 and looking at the circuit and datasheet I understand that the changing the inductor values will affect its current output. Currently the circuit is using a 68 uH 1/4 watt inductor and the output is about 30 mA. I wanted to use a 47 uH inductor but I only have it in 1/2 watt size. Will using a 1/2 watt rating inductor damage the circuit instead of 1/4 watt?


Inductors aren't usually rated in watts. Can you share the datasheets from which you got these ¼ W and ½ W numbers?

Axial DIP inductors has them. They looks like a through hole resistors with ring color bands. They have specified wattage. 1/4w 0307 is small whereas 1/2w 0410 is little bigger and 1w 0510 is big.

Size picture

When buying fixed value color ring inductor at ebay they have 1/4w, 1/2w and 1w sizes. I cannot link to the site because it's too long to fit in the comment.

You need to know the saturation current of your inductor. Size is a very rough measurement when it comes to inductors.

It should be fine as long as the LED can handle the higher current. Using a higher wattage rated component in place of a lower one is almost never a problem, the rating just means that it can dissipate more heat before burning out.
In the datasheet it shows a list of inductors for different currents with a 1.25 V battery, note that the 68 µH one is shown as a 0307 package (1/4 W) while the 47 µH part is shown as a 0410 package (1/2 W) so what you have should be what they're calling for.

Thanks. I'll use a higher rating current 8mm LED. They can use up to a 100mA. I was worry if the bigger size inductor might mess with they're switching frequency and may damage the IC.
